# Test if Spring Scope is active

Tags: spring, session, inversion-of-control, scope

How can I test if the Session scope is active in Spring? for example, at startup some classes need a User object which is Session scoped, than i return a mock User object.

the bean in question is declared with aop:scoped-proxy.
how can i test if the session scope is active?

Comment: If you're using scoped-proxies, why do you care if it's active or not? It'll just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick was to create a factory, obtain aop-scoped proxy from the factory and run any method that requires the actual object to be there and the scope, too.

then catch a BeanCreationException to detect the inactive scope.

Comment: Just a warning: I'm seeing a considerable performance hit due to Spring's proxy classes in such a usage of testing via allowing Spring to throw a BeanCreationException (using 4.2.4.RELEASE)

Comment: That's a terrible solution, but I also can't find anything better :(

Answer (score 1):

As the spring reference manual states in Chapter 3, session scope:

> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Your code, if invoked via a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext (most likely an XMLWebApplicationContext), will automatically be injected with different session scoped beans as they are invoked by different users as long as the proper spring configuration is set up to inject these session scoped beans.  Then, your code can ignore where they came from and focus on using the user attributes, etc, found in the session scoped bean - without worrying what actually injected the property.

So, I guess the true answer is that you cannot test this - but nor do you need to - if someone is asking you to do this, then "they're doing it wrong".